# Jenkins: DirectoryNotEmptyException: .../lastSuccessful

Tags: jenkins, docker

We are running Jenkins 1.651.1 in a Docker container.
On a certain moment we decided to move our containers to another environment.

We have a cron job which creates backups of the volume of our container:

```
tar -cvpzf jenkins-backup.tar -C jenkins-volume/_data/ . --exclude ".m2"
```

On the new environment we created a new jenkins docker volume:

```
docker volume create --name jenkins-volume
```

And we `untar` our backup inside the volume + recreated a jenkins instance and connected it with the volume

Everything is working fine again except we sometimes get an unexpected 'error' message. It doesn't break anything but appears very often:

```
Started by user ********
ln builds/lastSuccessfulBuild /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx/lastSuccessful failed
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx/lastSuccessful
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor473.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1233)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1151)
    at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1821)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1736)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ln builds/lastStableBuild /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx/lastStable failed
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx/lastStable
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor473.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1233)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1151)
    at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1822)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1736)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
... and it works further and fine
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Try removing the files builds/lastStableBuild and builds/lastSuccessfulBuild and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by CSchulz you can delete the directories and those will get created base on the result of the build.

This could also be because these are soft links & from the backup, these might be created as the directories. Hence, Jenkins not able to delete them. 
If you remove or rename these directories, Jenkins then can recreate the soft-links.